# Cannot refine String with CONSTANT

Tags: ruby

I'm currently exploring refinements in Ruby 2.1.1 and I'm running into something odd. I'm trying to refine the `String` class and define a constant called `FOO`.

**sandbox.rb**

```
module Foobar
  refine String do
    FOO = "BAR"

    def foobar
      "foobar"
    end
  end
end

using Foobar

puts "".class::FOO # => uninitialized constant String::FOO (NameError)
puts "".foobar # => "foobar"
```

This gives me `uninitialized constant String::FOO (NameError)`. I can however call `"".foobar` which leads me to believe this I am in the correct scope.

What's odd is that if I open  the `String` class and define `FOO` I get a different result.

**sandbox.rb**

```
class String
  FOO = "BAR"
end

puts "".class::FOO # => "BAR"
```

Why doesn't the refinement version of this work as I expect?

Comment: [See Here](http://dev.af83.com/2012/11/05/ruby-2-0-module-refine.html) you are acting in different scopes. `#refine` makes for safer monkey patching that will only implement inside another scope but the "refined" class will be ignorant of this change outside of that scope.

Comment: You cannot do it because it is different thing `refine` and reopen `class`. Then you `refine` this works like are method but `class` open and define constant it is another *magic*. `refine` make temporary changes to core class in a relatively safe way... and @engineersmnky be right you in another scope.

Comment: I don't understand how they're different scopes. I'm inside of a file and not inside any class so shouldn't I be at the top scope? I'm calling `puts "".class::FOO` the same way in both examples. Can you please explain in a little more detail in an answer?

Comment: Also, I added a `foobar` method to the refinement version of the code and I am successfully able to call `"".foobar` so now I'm even more confused than before :/

Comment: good point it may have something to do with how refinements implement and that they don't handle constants. I am trying to look into this further but documentation isn't as easy to come by as I'd like.

Comment: better yet try this `Foobar.constants` bet you it shows `[:FOO]` seems the constant is defined inside the module but not on `String` itself.

Comment: @engineersmnky i say about it, `FOO` constants inside a module not in the `String`.

Comment: That seems like a bug to me. If I'm inside of a refine block and I assign a constant it should be assigned to what I'm refining, not the module.

Comment: @kyledecot seems like you cannot redefine constants inside a refine block. Not sure if it is a bug because I think if it tried to define the constant inside the block it should then raise a `SyntaxError` for dynamic constant assignment.

Comment: It seems since refine acts upon the receiver. It allows you to define constants both inside and outside of the block before it interprets the method definitions. The behavior is strange in concept but functionally it makes sense since `refine` is designed to avoid collisions.

Comment: The same applies to class and instance variables. It seems that when creating `refinements` the encapsulation of the klass can utilize definitions outside of the block like a standard block can and that when evaluating the block it can pass items outside of itself which is very unblock like. I would report it just to see what the developers say. I would be very interested to understand how this block interpretation differs from all others in ruby.

Comment: I've created a bug report at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10103 if you'd like to chime in. Thanks for exploring this behavior so in depth!

Answer (score 2):

You can't refine constants and class variables with Refinements.

[Source: comment by Matz](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10103)

Comment: I like how you linked to *my* ticket :p

Comment: @KyleDecot I was tinkering with the same issue and thought it was relevant to add it here :)

Comment: Yeah, at first glance it seems like it would work but I get why it doesn't. If you feel strongly enough about it perhaps comment on the ticket so matz and the other core can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - this answer does not pretend. Just some research.

About `refine`:

Idea of a `refine`ment is to make a temporary, *limited-scope* change to a class. Feature is experimental(`Refinements are experimental, and the behavior may change in future versions of Ruby!`) sometimes behavior strange(like in your case).

About scope:

You `String` class constant `FOO` in another scope:

```
=> module Baz
=>   class String
=>     FOO = "ADw"
=>   end
=>   puts "".class::FOO # <- this should work ?
=> end
=> "".class::FOO
#> NameError: uninitialized constant String::FOO
=> Baz::String.new.class::FOO
#> "ADw"
=> String::FOO
#> uninitialized constant String::FOO
=> Baz.constants
#> [:String]
```

Some update:

```
=> module Bar
=>   refine String do
#>     WOO = "Fo"
=>   end
=> end
=> #<refinement:String@Bar>
=> Bar.constants
=> [:WOO]
```

Comment: My `String` class constant is not in a module. It's at the top level (in the monkey patching example)

Comment: @kyledecot  `refine`ments class  in a module.

Comment: @kyledecot it's actually not it is wrapped in a module that's what refine does

Comment: I understand that the `refine` version is in a module. I understand why his example doesn't work as he's not using `refine`. What I don't understand is why methods are available via refine but not constants.

Comment: I get what you're saying not but that doesn't seem like that's how it should behave.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation (sorry we weren't getting what you were saying at first). Do you think this is a bug or should be reported to the ruby team?

Comment: i think this not a bug, but strange logic behavior. Too hard search some info about using `refine`, try report i think can be helpful.

Comment: I've created a report at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10103 just to see what the core members have to say about it. Please feel free to chime in