# Refinements: can't build up mixin in 'using' context

Tags: ruby, refinements

Trying to extend functionality to ease usage/integration of `IceCube` in a `Rails` context, ended up using [Refinements](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html).

After encountering some limitations and reading some documentation, I am facing a last challenge that I have not seen documented anywhere. How comes the example below does not work.

The target class to extend functionality with some generic `Utils` is `Foo`:

```rb
class Foo; end

module Utils
  def bar; "bar"; end
end
```

This is done with a refinement called `RefFoo`, where some other refinements are meant to use `Utils` (i.e. `call_bar`):

```rb
module RefFoo
  refine Foo.singleton_class do
    include Utils
    def call_bar; bar; end
  end
end
```

- Refining the class methods as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27835057/4352306).

Let's say we are `using` the refinement within the context of a module called `RefinedFoo` (in the real case, a `Rails` service class):

```rb
module RefinedFoo
  using RefFoo

  class << self
    def bar;      Foo.bar;       end
    def call_bar; Foo.call_bar;  end
  end
end
```

Although the refinement is active, as shown by the result of the class method `Foo::bar` (via `RefinedFoo::bar`), invoking `Foo::call_bar` (via `RefinedFoo::call_bar`) throws a `NameError`:

```
RefinedFoo.bar
#=> "bar"
RefinedFoo.call_bar
#=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `bar' for Foo:Class)
```

- `Foo::call_bar` exists, however, for `Foo::call_bar` the method `Foo::bar` does NOT exist, regardless `include` was called.

There seems not to be a way around it, if we rewrite `RefFoo` to include an already mixed module, the error persists:

```rb
module RefFoo
  module Mixin
    include Utils
    def call_bar; bar; end
  end
  refine Foo.singleton_class do
    include Mixin
  end
end

# define RefinedFoo the same way

RefinedFoo.call_bar
#=> NameError (undefined local variable or method `bar' for Foo:Class)
```

And yet, if you `extend` `RefFoo` in a module, the error won't show up:

```rb
def Bar
  extend RefFoo::Mixin
end

Bar.call_bar
#=> "bar"
```

Obviously, I could just create a new class called `MyFoo` that inherits and extends `Foo` (i.e. `MyIceCube`) and work from there. Before I do, it would be great if I could get a bit more of context. Among other readings, went through these:

- [Why is nobody using Refinements?](https://interblah.net/why-is-nobody-using-refinements) Where it largely refers to the lexical scope of the `using` statement. Can't see how this applies to this example, though.
- [Cannot refine String with CONSTANT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25060874/4352306) This led to a [bug report on ruby master](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10103) where the team referred to constants and class variables as belonging to *outer class*, being prudent to do not touch this due to backwards incompatible changes to constant scoping rules.
- [How do I use an ActiveSupport Concern to add a refinement to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41773975/4352306) (I think that this one has a similar problem?)

Still unsure how the code above fits in any of the posts and articles. Are refinements just a method to implement very small and well localized (self-contained) patches? (i.e. can't `include` libraries of helpers to extend classes) and are NOT meant to be used for extending classes just in specific scopes of your app? Or I have just landed to this problem because I am trying to refine at class methods level?